# selenium grid - running tests simultaneously

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-grid

I have a test suite with a big amount of tests.
I would like those tests to run simultaneously by sending them to my HUB(assuming I have 2 Nodes). meaning, run all of my tests(locally or in Teamcity) and I'm expecting the result to be that Node1 will run test#1 while ,**at the same time**, Node2 will run test#2.
in fact, what's happening at the moment is that test#1 will run on Node1 and when it finishes, and just then, test#2 will be executed on Node2 and so on...

I can split my tests into two projects or open two sessions of Visual Studio and run them simultaneously, and the HUB will do the rest(right?) , but it sounds like a bad approach.

My code is written in C#.

Comment: Huge task , but not impossible

Comment: the hub is working as expected, just remember that you executing test framework has to work in parallel

Comment: @HenningLuther what does it mean that my executing test framework has to work in parallel? I'm working with Nunit

Comment: you execute your tests with a framework, right? in java we normally use testng where it runs in parallel. for me it seems, that your execution is single threaded

Comment: Yes, I'm using Nunit. 
So I need to search for how to run in multi thread?
as far as I understand the answer is yes, my executes are in single thread.

Comment: yes, exactly...

Comment: This should not be a huge task. I agree with above, just look at how to execute tests in parallel with NUnit. However, you need to also make sure that your tests don't edit shared data or you'll get inconsistent results when the test data for one test steps on another's toes.

Comment: 10x all. my biggest problem at the moment is to figure out how to do that in parallel, although it's bee said several times here it's not a big issue. Any link or guide will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a build that to run the test, e.g. task 1: node test test1, task 2 nude test test2.

Have a task that spawns 2 subshell and wait for both to finish. e,g, task 1: bash test1() node test1 & 
test2() node test2 &

the () means to run it in a sub shell, so that wll spawn a new thread for you, and the & means to run in background so that it will run both at the same time. Then you will need to somehow wait for both to end, either by doing a while -z ps-aux grep test1  (while there is a process of of regex test1)

If you want to run it on a seperate pc, then you can scp the file across to the other pc, and ssh to start the test, and then do while loop to wait for a finish.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code written in C# I assume you use NUnit and NUnit runner can run tests simultaneously since NUnit3 release, so all you need is to add

`[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]`

to your properties AssemblyInfo.cs file.
It worked for me.

Comment: should I add something in the test class as well, or it's just the assembly I need to add?

Comment: @Yaniv Eliav I added only it and everything worked out. If it would not work, you can try add parallelizable attribute to your tests

Comment: I have tried it with your `assembly` suggestion and parallelizable attribute.Both tests starts to run and executing the IE driver +navigating to the correct url, but then one of the tests keep failing with 404 error. I'm afraid I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Do you use standalone server for selenium?

Comment: Yes, I do . and I have two selenium-node connected.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that, you use same port for both nodes.

Comment: I do use same port but different IP's..is this should be an issue?

Comment: it can be. try to add -port <diffrent port> when start second node

Comment: actually when thinking about it, I can't use a different port since I'm connecting my nodes to the same hub.. isn't it?

Comment: this is how the Node(s) looks like: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -role node -hub http://10.1.72.209:4422/grid/register -browser browserName="internet explorer",version=11,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=1,applicationName=tvru2`

Comment: When you start your node it use default 5555 port, so when you start your second node, just add -port 5556 parametr to the end of comand

Comment: I'll try it and let you know. 10x!!

Comment: succeed running one of the node's in different port, but still, tests are not running simultaneously. It feels like that's the way..I'm probably missing something

Comment: Did you try to do it with another browser?

Comment: I can't. This is only being supported by IE

Comment: So, both nodes starts correctly and tests run on different nodes but not simultaneously?

Comment: they do run simultaneously, but just the `[setup]` block runs simultaneously and then only one of them keep running

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't how to help you. I think the problem is in IE browser

Comment: 10x anyway..I'll try to figure it out